# I want to increase my background's width in css how can i?

Tags: css

How to increase my background's width

Given below is my code.

```
#introSection {
    color: white;
    background: center / contain no-repeat url("/static/bg.jpg");
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You want to stretch it horizontally, or scale it in both directions? Should it have a fixed with or scale with the window?

Comment: yes i want to stretch the background image in the full section.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the basckgroud `cover` the div, simply change the line to this:

```
background: center / cover no-repeat url("/static/bg.jpg");
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) for more info on the various options you have for sizing a background.

Comment: but my image is  a bigger one. so, when i use cover  i am able to see a very few part of the image.

Comment: It is impossible to have the entire div be covered, the entire image visible, and the image not be stretched. Pick 2.

Comment: can i send you the screen shot of my page ?

Comment: You can edit your post to add more details yes

Comment: i don't know because i am a newbie

Comment: I can't help you if you can't explain what you are looking for exactly